# Google Drive for Android SDK Doesn't List Files

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I've got a really odd problem with the Google Drive Android SDK. I've been using it for several months now, and until last week it performed perfectly. However, there is now a really odd error, which doesn't occur all the time but does 9 out of 10 times.

I'm trying to list the user's files and folders stored in a particular Google Drive folder. When I'm trying to use the method Drive.files().list().execute(), 9 out of 10 times literally nothing happens. The method just hangs, and even if I leave it for an hour, it just remains doing... nothing.

The code I'm using is below - all of this being run within the doInBackground of an AsyncTask. I've checked credentials - they are all fine, as is the app's certificate's SHA1 hash. No exceptions are thrown. Google searches have yielded nothing. Here is the particular bit of code that's bothering me:

```
    try {
       GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                   SettingsActivity.this, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));

       if (googleAccountName != null && googleAccountName.length() > 0) {
          credential.setSelectedAccountName(googleAccountName);
    
           Drive service = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
    
           service.files().list().execute(); // Google Drive fails here
       } else {
          // ...
       }

    } catch (final UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {

       // Authorisation Needed
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               try {
                   startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORISE_GDRIVE);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   Log.e("SettingsActivity: Google Drive", "Unable to add Google Drive account due to Exception after trying to show the Google Drive authroise request intent, as the UserRecoverableIOException was originally thrown. Error message:\n" + e.getMessage());
               }
            }
       });
    
       Log.d("SettingsActivity: Google Drive", "UserRecoverableAuthIOException when trying to add Google Drive account. This is normal if this is the first time the user has tried to use Google Drive. Error message:\n" + e.getMessage());
       return;

    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("SettingsActivity: Google Drive", "Unable to add Google Drive account. Error message:\n" + e.getMessage());
       return;
    }
```

I'm using Drive API v2. Thanks everyone!

## Edit

Having played around a bit more, it turns out this isn't for just listing files. Trying to interact with any file on Google Drive behaves the same way - deleting, downloading, creating... Anything! I have also noticed that putting the device in aeroplane mode so it has not internet access makes no difference either: Google Drive doesn't throw an exception, or even return, it just freezes the thread it's on.

I've updated to the very latest Drive API lib but that hasn't helped. I remembered that the error happened soon after I added the JSch SSH library to the project, so I removed that, but it made no difference. Removing and re-adding the Drive API v2 has made no difference either, and nor has cleaning the project.

## Edit 2

I've found something which may be significant. On the Google Developer console, I had some Drive errors recorded as follows:

```
TOP ERRORS:
Requests  % Requests  Methods              Error codes
18        38.30%      drive.files.list     400   
14        29.79%      drive.files.insert   500  
11        23.40%      drive.files.update   500  
4         8.51%       drive.files.get      400
```

Do you reckon these are the errors? How could I fix them? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and it's work

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<File>>() {

    @Override
    protected List<File> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        try {   
            com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.List list = service.files().list();
            list.setQ("'" + sourcePath + "' in parents");
            FileList fileList = list.execute();
            result = fileList.getItems();
            if(result != null) {
                return result;
                }
           } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
           } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
           }
            return null;
           } 

    protected void onPostExecute(List<File> result) {
            //This is List file from Google Drive
    };
}.execute();
```

Comment: I just tried the code, but sorry, nothing happens. It just hangs, like before.

Comment: Would you like me to post the code for the service? As I said though, everything - including the service - worked perfectly until last week, so I can't imagine it would be that. But if you'd like to have a look I can post it

Comment: I've now posted much more complete code for you above. Is there anything there which looks wrong?

Comment: Maybe you need to check your SHA1 in Google APIs console, if you change your keystore that will be fail

Comment: I've just checked it on the Google Cloud Console. I've got both the debug and publishing keystore SHA1 there. They're both correct! I suspect it's more on the client side, because as I've noted in the original question, the Drive API behaves weird even if the device is in aeroplane mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution which does work, and thought I'd post it so others could see it if they happen to come across the problem.

Luckily, I had backed up all of the previous versions of the app. So I restored the whole project to how it was two weeks ago, copied and pasted all changes from the newer version which had been made since then, and it worked. I don't see why this should work, since the end result is the same project, but it does!

Answer (score 0):

**Google Drive List Files**

***This might help you.. Try to display it in ListView u will see all fetched folders***

```
 public void if_db_updated(Drive service)
{
   try {

         Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'");

          FileList files = request.execute();

          for(File file : files.getItems())
           {        

                 String title = file.getTitle();                             
                showToast(title);


           }

       }  catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
              startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


}

 public void showToast(final String toast) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
```